# How to NOT OVERWRITE but put content in the middle of a file?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to write a c++ code that will put some additional text in the middle  that not overwrite. I have tried every possible combination of tags but none of them are working. Can anybody give me an working example ?
For example :-
if input is :-

Hello!
Hey are you there ?
Is anybody home ?

Then the output should be :-

Hello!
Hey are you there ?
Where are you ?
Is anybody home ?

The Where are you text is inserted in the middle.I'm using c++ file handling.

Comment: What did you try what didn't work? There is not "out of the box" append write that is not at the end of the file. You have to "move" the rest of the bytes.

Comment: I was trying to do it by calling some write function,but I guess there is no other way other then moving the bytes myself as you are saying. I will try it your way.

Comment: Seek to the position you want to insert the text, save the rest of the text until EOF, write what you need and then append the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think that files work alot like arrays in that you can't just do an easy insert.  For instance if you are implementing a vector or arraylist and want to insert a value in the middle you must shit all values after that.  To insert in the middle I think you will need to shift all the contents bellow.  I would maybe read everything into memory first or use a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a limitation of C++ but of the underlying filesystem (on most modern file-systems).
A file is a block(s) of contiguous bytes, you can not append in the middle.

You have two options:

1. Read the file into memory.
   Manipulate the file in memory
   Overwrite the old file.
2. Open the file for reading and a temporary file for writing.
   Copy from input file to output file until you get to the point you want to add text.
   Write the modifications and finish the copy.
   Replace the file with the tempfile.